# Router.match is not been called on every route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have server side rendering app and using react-router for routing. I was using **Router.Run** Before as the method is no more I am using **Router.Match**.Previously when there was route change router.run used to be called but same behavior is not happening in the router.match. Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: i am not able to fully understand your problem.can you share your code>

Answer (score 0):

I have defined my router in entry module defined below and it will go to Layout component to look for route paths:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}> 
    //<IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="archives" name="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
    <Route path="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
    <Route path="featured" component={Featured}></Route>
    </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app'));
```

Layout component will bind the path defined in router to different components in Layout Component

```
import { Link } from "react-router";
    class Layout extends React.Component(

    render(){
    return(

    {this.props.children}
     <li><MenuItem><Link to="archives">archives</Link></MenuItem></li>
             <li><MenuItem><Link to="settings">settings</Link></MenuItem></li>
             <li><MenuItem><Link to="featured">featured</Link></MenuItem></li>
    )

    }        
             );
```

You can define any action for your route components.its working fine for me