# How to pass props to this.props.children using React Router 4 with switch?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having nesting as follows with switch using react router 4

```
<MainComponent>
  <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
  <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
  <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
<MainComponent>
```

On main component page i am having some state which i want to pass as props to this.props.children.
In Main component render method i had written {this.props.children} to access children component. Now how to pass my CustomProps to this.props.children

Thanks in Advance for help

Comment: Here is the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your state is day:monday.then you need to pass the state in child as

```
<MainComponent>
  <ChildComponent day={this.state.day}/>

<MainComponent>
```

And in your child component ChildComponent you can get your state using

```
this.props.day
```

Comment: but in my main component in render method i am passing {this.props.children} so i want to know how to pass custom props to {this.props.children} using React Router 4 in ES6

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796916/router-match-is-not-been-called-on-every-route-change/43797059#43797059